# How to search Gmail for emails based on number of recipients

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, search, gmail-search

I've been given the task of searching our company emails for emails that were sent to 10+ recipients, to check for accidentally included mailing lists.

I've checked all the documentation I can find about how search works in Gmail and I can find many articles talking about how to filter by specific recipients, but none of them cover how to search based on the number of recipients.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Maybe something like:

```
to: * AND * AND * AND * AND * OR *
```

or

```
to:(qty > 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Gmail Does Not Support That

In Gmail's web application you **cannot** perform wildcard (*) searches, nor can you perform a search based on quantity. e.g.  "5 recipients" or "5 words" or "5 messages in thread"

##### Gmail API

In order to perform searches that are not supported in the Gmail web application one needs to leverage the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides).

This could be done on your behalf via a third party mail application, or done yourself using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).

Every Google account comes with access to a private  [Apps Script Project portal](https://script.google.com/home).  There you could, for example, write or paste a script to go through your sent items and identify all sent messages that include 10+ recipients and apply a label to any found such as `10 plus recipients`.

You could even use Google Apps Script to create report in Google Sheets of the identified emails with the subjects, date, and their  recipient lists.